# Exit in ssh log me out instead of disconnecting

Tags: ssh

When I login to a remote machine via ssh, I have to enter a password first and then login to the OS itself by entering another pair of login and a password. When I'm doing I type exist. However, it doesn't terminate the ssh session, instead if logs me out from the OS:

```
[machine_name@login123 folder_name]$ exit
logout

CentOS release 6.2 (Final)
Kernel 3.14.5-x86-linode61 on an i686

machine_name login:
```

How do I disconnect from the ssh session?

Comment: This is for some kind of remote console / out-of-band management rather than a direct connection to the machine, right? When you ssh directly to the machine I can't imagine this happens?

Comment: What command did you use to make the initial connection?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman, ssh.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, it's ssh.

Comment: What output do you get from the tty and who am i commands? This isn't behaving like a normal ssh session. That output might clarify thimgs.

Comment: @Grienders I don't question that you connect using ssh. What I question is what you are connecting to, ie I think you are connecting to something else than the machine itself. (See my previous comment.)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, I connect to CentoOS.

Comment: @Grienders Based on the "-linode61" in the kernel version i wager this is what you've connected to instead of the machine itself: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish

Comment: @Grienders https://www.linode.com/docs/getting-started#finding-the-ip-address seems to be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not typical ssh behavior. It sounds like the remote server has been configured in some unusual way. In any event, when `ssh` is running interactively, it accepts a set of escape sequences to invoke special behavior. One of these escape sequences will cause `ssh` to disconnect and exit.

To disconnect, type `<CR>~.`. That means to press your return key (aka the enter key), then tilde (`~`), then period.

There are other sequences you can type. typing `<CR>~?` (return, tilde, question-mark) will print a list. You can also see a list by viewing [the `ssh` man page](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh) and searching for "ESCAPE CHARACTERS".